# SQL: How to get multiple records from xml column

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have an xml which looks like this. `<name_row>` nodes has the column names and `<value_row>` has all the values. How do I cross join?

```
Declare @myXML xml
SET @myXML = '<root>
 <name_row>
  <column>  
     <name>CustomerID</name>
   </column>
     <column>  
     <name>ProductID</name>
   </column>
   <column>  
     <name>Price</name>
   </column>
</name_row>
<value_row>  
   <column>  
     <value>123</value>
   </column>
    <column>  
     <value>101</value>
   </column> 
    <column>  
     <value>$12.00</value>
   </column>      
</value_row>
<value_row>  
   <column>  
     <value>123</value>
   </column>
    <column>  
     <value>102</value>
   </column> 
    <column>  
     <value>$15.00</value>
   </column>      
</value_row>
</root>'
```

I need to save each values in a different column fields.

```
select x.i.value('(./text()[1]', 'varchar(max)')
from @myXML x 
cross apply x.nodes('/root/value_row/column/value') as x(i)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
select v.value('(column/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as CustomerID
     , v.value('(column/value)[2]', 'varchar(max)') as ProductID
     , v.value('(column/value)[3]', 'varchar(max)') as Price
into #tempTable
from @myXML.nodes('root/value_row') t(v)

select * from #tempTable

drop table #tempTable
```